# Force.com IDE - Eclipse Plugin doesn't work?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, salesforce, apex-code, force.com, force-ide

I'm new to Apex and have just downloaded Eclipse to get to work

Eclipse SDK 3.3.2

I've followed the instructions on

http://wiki.apexdevnet.com/index.php/Force.com_IDE_Installation_for_Eclipse_3.3.x

and have added the Remote site:

http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/install/

but i get a dialog telling me

"No features found on the selected site(s). Choose a different site or site category"

Any ideas what i've done wrong??

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that process from a [clean eclipse install](http://community.salesforce.com/sforce/board/message?board.id=scontrols&thread.id=1975), and repeat the installation steps, making sure that before clicking on "Finish" you unselect the checkbox at the lower left: "Ignore features not applicable to this environment".

Also, check if http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/install/ is accessible from your workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your proxy setting by accessing "http://www.adnsandbox.com/tools/ide/install/" URL in any of browser and update proxy setting in eclipse.

Comment: Thanks, after investigation turns out WebSense blocked the request... Oh how I hate it! Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest Eclipse Ganymede and try that. 
Another good news for you is, force.com is coming with Eclipse galileo plugin in coming release.

Answer (score 0):

Force.com now has a standalone development environment that you don't need to download Eclipse for. Just putting it out there for people who stumble across this post.